# Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 installation error on Installing module: Sitecore Commerce ExperienceAnalytics Core

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework, installation, commerce-engine

Been stuck here for a while...
Installing Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 Update-2 on Sitecore XP 9.0.2

This is my first time installing XC.

The script used is shown after the log.

This is the error log:

```
[---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- InstallModule : InstallModule
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------] Installing module:  Sitecore Commerce ExperienceAnalytics Core
11.2.83.zip http://sxa.storefront.com/SiteUtilityPages/InstallModules.aspx?modules=Sitecore Commerce ExperienceAnalytics Core 11.2.83.zip
********************** Command start time: 20180801112334
********************** PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-RestMethod): "


        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top:
-5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }





            Server Error in '/' Application.

             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event. 



             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.



             Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

            Source Error: 






Line 52:         context.AddAspect&lt;IFileInstallerEvents&gt;(events); Line 53:  Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context); Line 55: Line 56:         // Execute Post Step







             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx &nbsp;&nbsp; Line:  54


            Stack Trace: 






[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the &#39;item:saved&#39; event.]    Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1848    Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390    Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294    System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0    Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +135    Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202    Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229    Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98    (Object , Object ) +14    Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484    Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127    Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126    Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28    Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version)
+343    Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode, IProcessingContext context, Boolean removeOtherVersions) +126    Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry)
+1304    Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156    Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102    Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228    Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565    Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80    Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source, IProcessingContext context)
+444    Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72    ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54 ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36 System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +154    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+4082










            Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0





"
>> TerminatingError(Invoke-RestMethod): "


        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top:
-5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }





            Server Error in '/' Application.

             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event. 



             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.



             Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

            Source Error: 






Line 52:         context.AddAspect&lt;IFileInstallerEvents&gt;(events); Line 53:  Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context); Line 55: Line 56:         // Execute Post Step







             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx &nbsp;&nbsp; Line:  54


            Stack Trace: 






[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the &#39;item:saved&#39; event.]    Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1848    Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390    Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294    System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0    Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +135    Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202    Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229    Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98    (Object , Object ) +14    Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484    Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127    Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126    Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28    Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version)
+343    Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode, IProcessingContext context, Boolean removeOtherVersions) +126    Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry)
+1304    Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156    Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102    Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228    Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565    Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80    Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source, IProcessingContext context)
+444    Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72    ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54 ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36 System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +154    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+4082










            Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0





" Install-SitecoreConfiguration : 


        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top:
-5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }





            Server Error in '/' Application.

             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event. 



             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please  review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.



             Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the  subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

            Source Error: 






Line 52:         context.AddAspect&lt;IFileInstallerEvents&gt;(events); Line 53:  Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context); Line 55: Line 56:         // Execute Post Step







             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx &nbsp;&nbsp; Line:  54


            Stack Trace: 






[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the &#39;item:saved&#39;  event.]    Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1848    Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390    Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294    System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0    Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +135    Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202    Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229    Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98    (Object , Object ) +14    Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484    Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127    Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126    Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28    Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version)
+343    Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode,  IProcessingContext context, Boolean removeOtherVersions) +126    Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry)
+1304    Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156    Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102    Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228    Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565    Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80    Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source,  IProcessingContext context)
+444    Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72    ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54 ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36 System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +154    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
+4082










            Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0






At C:\Program  Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration Install-SitecoreConfiguration :


        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top:
-5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }





            Server Error in '/' Application.

             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.



             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.



             Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

            Source Error:






Line 52:         context.AddAspect&lt;IFileInstallerEvents&gt;(events); Line 53: Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context); Line 55: Line 56:         // Execute Post Step







             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx &nbsp;&nbsp; Line:  54


            Stack Trace:






[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the &#39;item:saved&#39; event.]    Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1848    Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390    Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294    System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0    Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +135    Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202    Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229    Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98    (Object , Object ) +14    Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484    Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127    Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126    Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28    Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version)
+343    Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode, IProcessingContext context, Boolean removeOtherVersions) +126    Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry)
+1304    Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156    Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102    Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228    Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565    Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80    Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source, IProcessingContext context)
+444    Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72    ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54 ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename.web\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36 System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +154    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+4082

            Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0

At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:02:16
********************** Windows PowerShell transcript end End time: 20180801112337
**********************
```

Script used:

```
#Requires -Version 3
param(
    [string]$SiteName = "websitename.web",  
    [string]$SiteHostHeaderName = "sxa.storefront.com", 
    [string]$SqlDbPrefix = $SiteName,
    [string]$CommerceSearchProvider = "SOLR"
)

$global:DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$modulesPath=( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "Modules" )
if ($env:PSModulePath -notlike "*$modulesPath*")
{
    $p = $env:PSModulePath + ";" + $modulesPath
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath",$p)
}


$params = @{
        Path = Resolve-Path '.\Configuration\Commerce\Master_SingleServer.json' 
        SiteName = $SiteName
        SiteHostHeaderName = $SiteHostHeaderName 
        InstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$SiteName"
        XConnectInstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$($SiteName)_xconnect"
        CertificateName = $SiteName
        CommerceServicesDbServer = $($Env:COMPUTERNAME)    #OR "SQLServerName\SQLInstanceName"
        CommerceServicesDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments"
        CommerceServicesGlobalDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_Global"       
        SitecoreDbServer = $($Env:COMPUTERNAME)            #OR "SQLServerName\SQLInstanceName"
        SitecoreCoreDbName = "$($SqlDbPrefix)_Core"
        SitecoreUsername = "sitecore\admin"
        SitecoreUserPassword = "b"
        CommerceSearchProvider = $CommerceSearchProvider
        SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr"
        SolrRoot = "C:\sitecore\solr-6.6.2"
        SolrService = "solr6"
        SolrSchemas = ( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "SolrSchemas" )
        SearchIndexPrefix = ""
        AzureSearchServiceName = ""
        AzureSearchAdminKey = ""
        AzureSearchQueryKey = ""
        CommerceEngineDacPac = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK.*\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.DB.dacpac"       
        CommerceOpsServicesPort = "5015"
        CommerceShopsServicesPort = "5005"
        CommerceAuthoringServicesPort = "5000"
        CommerceMinionsServicesPort = "5010"        
        SitecoreCommerceEngineZipPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.2.2.126.zip"        
        SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.BizFX.1.2.19"        
        SitecoreIdentityServerZipPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.IdentityServer.1.*.zip"
        CommerceEngineCertificatePath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\websitename9.local.cer"      
        SiteUtilitiesSrc = ( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "SiteUtilityPages" )  
        HabitatImagesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Habitat.Images-*.zip"    
        AdvImagesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Adventure Works Images.zip"    
        CommerceConnectModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Connect*.zip"  
        CommercexProfilesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce ExperienceProfile Core *.zip"    
        CommercexAnalyticsModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce ExperienceAnalytics Core *.zip" 
        CommerceMAModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Marketing Automation Core *.zip"    
        CommerceMAForAutomationEngineModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Marketing Automation for AutomationEngine *.zip" 
        CEConnectPackageFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect*.update"
        PowerShellExtensionsModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions-4.7.2.zip"
        SXAModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.7.1 rev. 180604 for 9.0.zip"
        SXACommerceModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator 1.*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront 1.*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontThemeModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront Themes*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontCatalogModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Habitat Catalog*.zip"
        MergeToolFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"
        UserAccount = @{
            Domain = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
            UserName = 'CSFndRuntimeUser'
            Password = 'Pu8azaCr'
        }
        BraintreeAccount = @{
            MerchantId = ''
            PublicKey = ''
            PrivateKey = ''
        }
        SitecoreIdentityServerName = "SitecoreIdentityServer"       
    }

if ($CommerceSearchProvider -eq "SOLR") {
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params
}
elseif ($CommerceSearchProvider -eq "AZURE"){
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Skip InstallSolrCores
}
```

Comment: Is your xconnect site running while installation? And is xconnect working? If not start it and the error should not appear. Best regards
Chris

Comment: Thanks @Christian it worked! now I get a different error at later stage... :(

Comment: @Christian It would be awesome if you can help me out with this! https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13159/sitecore-experience-commerce-xc-9-0-2-installation-error-at-get-token-from-site Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my machine, i have some problem with xConnect client certificates and i got the same error.Even after making sure xConnect site works, i got the same error.
The root cause of error is saving "/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Experience Analytics/Dimensions/Connect/By campaigns for orders placed/All campaigns for orders placed" item.I was able to solve this error by commenting out the following configuration in "\App_Config\Sitecore\ExperienceAnalytics\Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.config" file.Hope this will help installing the commerce modules bypassing the xCOnnect certificate issues.

```
<event name="item:saved">
            <handler type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.Events.SegmentDeployedEventHandler, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client" method="OnItemSaved">
                <param
                    type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.DeploySegmentDefinitionProcessor, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client">
                    <param ref="experienceAnalytics/client/logger" />
                    <param type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentStore, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core">
                    </param>
                </param>
            </handler>
        </event>
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive this is happening because `sitecoreinstance.xconnect` is stopped at IIS. I manually stopped the website and got this error and at the next installation I did not stop it and Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0.3 installed successfully.